# ¿Cómo verificar si un TQuery devuelve algún resultado en Delphi?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, delphi

Estoy tratando de averiguar si existe un registro en base de datos, ejecuto una consulta `select` y quiero obtener el resultado, aún no puedo lograrlo ...

**Base de datos**

Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta directamente en la base de datos:

```
SELECT T.ID
FROM TABLA T
WHERE ID=3
```

Se obtiene:

```
No rows returned
```

Ahora trato de mostrar un mensaje en Delphi diciendo que el registro no existe.

En el formulario tengo un componente tipo `TQuery` llamado `qValidacion` correctamente conectado con base de datos Oracle 11g.

**Intento 1**

```
procedure TfPrueba.ButtonAceptarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    qValidacion.Close;
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('SELECT T.ID');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('FROM TABLA T');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('WHERE ID=3');
    qValidacion.Open;
    qValidacion.First;
    if qValidacion.IsEmpty then //No se como validar si el Select regresa algo, IsEmpty me muestra los registros existentes
        begin
             ShowMessage('El registro No Existe');
        end;
    qValidacion.SQL.Clear;
end;
```

**Intento 2**

```
procedure TfPrueba.ButtonAceptarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    qValidacion.Close;
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('SELECT T.ID');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('FROM TABLA T');
    qValidacion.SQL.Add('WHERE ID=3');
    qValidacion.Open;
    qValidacion.First;
    if (not qValidacion.Eof) then 
        begin
             ShowMessage('El registro No Existe'); //deberia mostrar el mensaje, pero no lo muestra
        end;
    qValidacion.SQL.Clear;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad `IsEmpty` de TDataSet devuelve verdadero si el conjunto de datos está vacío.

En general, con cualquier componente descendiente de TDataSet esto debiera funcionar:

```
qValidacion.Close;
qValidacion.SQL.Text := 'select t.ID from tabla t where t.id = 3';
qValidacion.Open;
if (qValidacion.IsEmpty) then
  raise Exception.Create('El registro no existe');
```

Ahora, `TQuery` es un componente que es parte de la primera capa de conexión estándar que vino con Delphi, llamada **Borland Database Engine** (BDE), y está marcado como obsoleto hace muchos años. Es probable que el driver de oracle de BDE esté teniendo inconvenientes (o que siempre los haya tenido, no logro recordar), y esté trayendo una fila con todos los campos en `null` (recuerdo haber visto este comportamiento con Firebird en algún momento.

Puedes hacer dos cosas:

### Con BDE y un driver que trae una fila con valores null

Si este es el caso, entonces, verifica que el valor recuperado no sea nulo, por ejemplo esto funcionaría en el caso particular que planteas:

```
qValidacion.Close;
qValidacion.SQL.Text := 'select t.ID from tabla t where t.id = 3';
qValidacion.Open;
if (qValidacion.Fields[0].IsNull) then
  raise Exception.Create('El registro no existe');
```

*Ojo* que esta solución no puedes generalizarla, ya que puede haber un caso donde recuperes un valor `null` de una fila que **si** existe en la base de datos, por lo mismo otra opción sería contar los registros, por ejemplo:

```
qValidacion.Close;
qValidacion.SQL.Text := 'select count(t.ID) Cuenta from tabla t where t.id = 3';
qValidacion.Open;
if (qValidacion.Fields[0].AsInteger = 0) then
  raise Exception.Create('El registro no existe');
```

### Cambiate a una capa de conexión a base de datos moderna

Esta es la verdadera respuesta. Incluso si usas versiones antiguas de Delphi, como Delphi 7, puedes utilizar [DBExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/DbExpress_Framework), o idealmente, si tienes una versión moderna de Delphi, la recomendación actual es utilizar **[FireDac](http://www.embarcadero.com/es/products/rad-studio/firedac)**

Answer (score 1):

Otra cosa que debería funcionar es algo como esto:

```
if (qValidacion.Eof) and (qValidacion.Bof) then
  // recordset vacío
  ...
```

Pero también debería funcionar el **IsEmpty** que tú comentas. Pruébalo a ver si con este hay más suerte.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy teniendo un problema parecido... aquí muestro mi código:

```
     SQLTraeCedula.SQL.Clear;
     SQLTraeCedula.SQL.Add('Select * from Cedula ' );
     SQLTraeCedula.SQL.Add('Where Cedula = :C ');
     SQLTraeCedula.Parameters.ParamByName('C').Value := QuotedStr(DBECedula.Text);
     SQLTraeCedula.Open;
   
    if not SQLTraeCedula.Fields[0].IsNull then
       begin
          ShowMessage('ERROR: Cédula ya Existe en la Tabla');
          DBECedula.SetFocus;
          DBECedula.Clear;
       end
     else
       DBENombre.SetFocus;
```

Pero esto no funciona, es decir cuando está el dato me dice que no está y viceversa.....

Cómo puedo resolver eso???

Comment: Hola. No añadas una respuesta para una duda o problema que tengas. Para esto añade una pregunta nueva. Te invito a leer como preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] y a hacer el recorrido: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour]. Saludos.